# Splunk limits the results returned by stats list() function

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I have a splunk query which returns a **list** of values for a particular field. The number of values can be far more than 100 but the number of results returned are limited to 100 rows and the warning that I get is this-

***'stats' command: limit for values of field 'FieldX' reached. Some values may have been truncated or ignored.***

The query in question can be as simple as this -

***| stats list(FieldX)***

Please note that I can't use ***table FieldX***  since I want the results to be grouped based on another field. Also I can't use ***stats values(FieldX)*** since I am extracting 2 fields from an event and these fields have one to one mapping, if I use ***stats values()***, the order is messed up.

I tried ***stats list(values) limit=500*** but it isn't helping. How can I have all the results returned?

Comment: What is your *actual* search now? Do you have any sample data? It's *likely* there's another way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The search looks like this-
| stats list(Field1) list(Field2) by Field3 Field4.

field1 and field2 have one to one mapping in events and i want to maintain it.

Comment: Original question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689944/group-events-by-multiple-fields-in-splunk

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800801/4418) on your first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63689944/4418) *should* handle this one, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option if you have a hard requirement to use *list(values)* logic is to increase the value *list_maxsize* from *limits.conf*. See the complete limits.conf manual entry here: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/limitsconf#.5Bstats.7Csistats.5D

*list_maxsize* is a system wide configuration so you'll have to:

- establish a console connection to the Splunk instance
- edit the limits.conf changing *list_maxsize = 500*
- restart splunk process

```
list_maxsize = <integer>
* Maximum number of list items to emit when using the list() function
  stats/sistats
* Default: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `list_maxsize` attribute in limits.conf to a higher value.  Be warned that this will cause the query to use more memory.  Remember to restart Splunk after changing the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800801/4418) to your other, related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63689944/4418)

Quoting the search from it:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Location=* Client=* TransactionNumber=* TransactionTime=*
| eval TNTT=TransactionNumber+" sep "+TransactionTime
| stats values(TNTT) as TNTT by Location Client
| rex field=TNTT "(?<TransactionNumber>\S+) sep (?<TransactionTime>.+)"
| table Location Client TransactionNumber TransactionTime
```

---

Note: you *may* need to reorder the `eval` line with which fields are added when for sorting via `values()` in the `|stats` line (and reorder the corresponding `rex` order, too)

Comment: This helps. Thanks. Learnt something. (:

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do in your sub search is:

| table FieldX
| mvcombine FieldX

That way, you actually create a `stats list(FieldX)`, without using stats.